# Materialize CSS and JQUERY - Sidebar active class does not add?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, materialize

My sidebar is composed of HTML and Materialize CSS and I'm trying to add an active class to a listitem every time I navigate using the sidebar.

```
                <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed sidebar">
                    <li class="logo">
                        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
                            <img class="responsive-img" src="Images/communicarelogo.png" />
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="healthrecord" class="bold">
                        <a href="HealthRecords.aspx" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Health Records</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="medmgt" class="bold">
                        <a href="MedicationsManagement.aspx" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Medications Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="healthprogram" class="bold">
                        <a href="HealthPrograms.aspx" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Health Programs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="reports" class="bold">
                        <a href="Reports.aspx" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Reports</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="bold">
                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-teal">My Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="bold">
                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-teal">Change Password</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I tried to use JQUERY but it isn't working. The active class **doesn't show** on ANY list item. Here is my JQUERY code.

```
$(function () {
    var link = $('.sidebar-nav li a');
    var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    $(link).each(function () {
        switch (pgurl) {
            case "HealthRecords.aspx":
                $('#healthrecord').addClass('active');
                break;
            case "MedicationsManagement.aspx":
                $('#medmgt').addClass('active');
                break;
            case "HealthPrograms.aspx":
                $('#healthprogram').addClass('active');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your classes are wrong! the name of your ul is : side-nav and not sidebar-nav.
Second you don't need to use the switch case Just check the href of each one:

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $(".side-nav li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Hahaha I wasnt able to double check! Thank, man!